# Import a module from my crate in a Criterion benchmark

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-criterion

I would like to benchmark functions created in my module, but I don't understand how I can import the module to then use the functions. My folders structure is the following

```
project
|-benches
  |-benchmarks.rs
|-src
  |-one
    |-mod.rs
  |-main.rs
```

And I would like to access the `one` module in the file `benchmarks.rs`. Can I do that? How? Thanks!

Comment: Your crate ("project") is accessible as a crate to your benchmark test(s). Add `use project::one::whatever_it_is` and go from there.